# windows .bat script to search for files that existed in the same directory previously

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I need to write a script that looks for same files that existed previously in the same directory. This script will be run as a scheduled job so it doesn't need to have the rerun functionality built in to it:

1. Look for files in a given directory.
2. If no files exist then return 0 and exit.
3. If files exist then store them and exit..
4. When script runs again (through a scheduler), look for files in the same directory and if any file names match with any files that were previously stored then print the file names that matched and return a non-zero exit code (1).
5. If there was no match then release the previously stored file names and store the new file names. Return 0 and exit.

Is it possible to achieve the above? I have no scripting backgrounds so any help will be beneficial.

Comment: It's definitely possible, and that's even the algorithm you would use to do it. I'd recommend looking at the outputs of `dir /?`, `for /?` and `findstr /?` while remembering that `>` writes to a new file while overwriting any existing data, and `>>` adds on to a file without overwriting anything.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "targetdir=U:\destdir"
SET "savedir=U:\"
SET /a returnlevel=0
DIR /b "%targetdir%">"%savedir%\newlist.txt"
IF NOT exist "%savedir%\oldlist.txt" GOTO noold
:: Now compare
FINDSTR /i /l /x /c:":" /g:"%savedir%\oldlist.txt" "%savedir%\newlist.txt"
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (SET /a returnlevel=0) ELSE (SET /a returnlevel=1)

:noold
MOVE /y "%savedir%\newlist.txt" "%savedir%\oldlist.txt" >NUL 2>nul
EXIT /b %returnlevel%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `targetdir` and `savedir` to suit your circumstances.